# Windows 8 upgrade to windows 8.1 Pro fails with error code 0xC1900101 - 0x2000C

Tags: windows-8

I have a new Dell desktop XPS 8700 i5 ; 12GB Ram ; 4 cpus @ 3 GHz ; 1 TB HHD

The download and checking went error free.  It asked to restart to do the install then after 26 Percent of the install it Errored out with Error Code  0xC1900101 - 0x2000C... Then reverted back to Windows 8 ?  Any guesses...

Comment: I think you're having effectively the same problem as this fellow, and me: http://superuser.com/questions/661311/windows-8-1-upgrade-fails-with-error-code-0xc1900101-0x20017 But it's not *quite* the same. I never even got a percentage.

Comment: did you update to Windows 8.1 before you upgraded to 8.1 Pro?

Comment: @BenPlont the author already had Windows 8 Professional

Comment: Did This happen more than once?  Be sure you have installed all updates before you attempt again

Comment: @Ramhound are you sure? OP says the move is from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1 Pro. I don't see anywhere in the post that says the starting OS was the Pro edition.

Comment: @BenPlont It wouldn't matter I have done manual Core to Windows 8.1 Pro migration without issue.  Besides he used the Windows Store method which means...it had to be Professional

Comment: I am facing the exactly same error. Any luck so far in solving it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Disconnect all the devices connected to your computer. (HDD, keyboard, printer, second monitor)
2. Remove directory "$windows.~bt" in C:/
3. <kbd>Windows key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> press
4. Enter **wsreset.exe** and hit Enter
5. Restart your computer.
6. You try to update again.

The command resets the Windows Store cache without removing installed apps or account settings.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can tell us in simple language what this actually command does lest it does something undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/949358

It is one of the fixes for 8.1 Update problems.