# Many error Windows 8.1 0xc190010- 0x20003, 0x2000D finally 0x20006 Still Stuck for trying

Tags: windows-8.1-upgrade

I trying to update windows 8.1, then got the error, Couldn't update to windows 8.1, then the status showed as "we've restored your previous version of windows 8 to this pc 0xC1900101 - 0x20006" All usb devices are disconnected, all antivirus is uninstall only windows 8 64-bit without media center lasted windows updated for windows and MS office 2010. Please help !!!!!

Comment: Have a look at these and see if they solve your problem http://superuser.com/questions/662163/windows-8-1-upgrade-fail-with-error-0xc1900101#comment836122_662163  http://superuser.com/questions/661311/windows-8-1-upgrade-fails-with-error-code-0xc1900101-0x20017

Answer (score 0):

Solved: My PC able to upgrade by disabling the on-board sound device. For my PC during the upgrading the anti-virus, usb devices and installed programs are not the problem. The windows 8.1 is fast and very good improvement.

Comment: Please mark this answer as the correct one so the problem can be closed.